# Broadcast not recieved when called by an intent

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have broadcast which is recieved on system boot as well as by an intent. This broadcast is to set alarm.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("recievers.BroadCastBootRec");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

My Broadcast class :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    c = context;
    Log.d("HirakDebug", "BroadCast Recieved");
    getDatesFromDatabase();
    getDateDifference();
    setAlarmI();
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".recievers.BroadCastBootRec"
        android:label="BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

IT IS RECIEVED ON SYSTEM REBOOT BUT NOT BY THE INTENT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register two actions
and to make things clear.
android:name is the Class name of the receiver you had written, not the action.
So, for the below receiver your receiver class name will be "BroadCastBootRec"

```
<receiver android:name=".recievers.BroadCastBootRec"
    android:label="BootReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.BroadCastBootRec" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>


Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.BroadCastBootRec");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

The android system will inform your receiver when ever an action **BOOT_COMPLETED** and **com.example.BroadCastBootRec** is triggered

```
public class BroadCastBootRec extends BroadcastReceiver 
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   c = context;
   Log.d("HirakDebug", "BroadCast Recieved");
   getDatesFromDatabase();
   getDateDifference();
   setAlarmI();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add custom action on intent filter :

```
<action android:name="recievers.BroadCastBootRec" />
```

**Example :**

```
<receiver android:name=".recievers.BroadCastBootRec"
   android:label="BootReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      <action android:name="recievers.BroadCastBootRec" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: thnk u very much... i accepted the other answer bcoz he was first to answer it. and i have seen u r very active here in stackoverflow in answering questions of others. thats really gud... solving their problems (y)

Comment: @HirakChhatbar,NP glad to help you and thanks for compliment.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be something like

MainActivity.java

```
public void broadcastCustomIntent(View view)
{
   Intent intent = new Intent("MyCustomIntent");

   EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.extraIntent);
   // add data to the Intent
   intent.putExtra("message", (CharSequence)et.getText().toString());
   intent.setAction("com.javacodegeeks.android.A_CUSTOM_INTENT");
   sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

In MyBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Extract data included in the Intent
    CharSequence intentData = intent.getCharSequenceExtra("message");   
    Toast.makeText(context, "Javacodegeeks received the Intent's message: "+intentData,    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

In app's Manifest file

```
  <receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.javacodegeeks.android.A_CUSTOM_INTENT">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```